# confusion in application of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

some say we use triple integral to find volume but volume under a surface [whose height(z-axis
depends on x and y axis]can be found by double integration.Also I have heard that  we use double integral to find area but area under a curve[whose height(z-axis
depends on x axis] can be found by single integration.

> > I am totally confused.
> >     **please somebody give me a chart of the applications of single,double and triple integrals**